# Flask APScheduler production

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, apscheduler

I am creating API in python-flask for first time. I am following this tutorial [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). Everything is working fine and Flask-APScheduler too when I used nohup python. When I configured uWSGI and Nginx by tutorial my API is working but APScheduler doesnt work and I dont know why. Thank you for response.

```
wsgi.py
zlty.ini
config.py
app
    __init__.py
    zlty.py
```

config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
DEBUG = True
APNS_CERTIFICATE = 'prodnopass.pem'
APNS_SANDBOX = False
JOBS = [
        {
            'id': 'first',
            'func': 'app.zlty:firstRoutes',
            'trigger': 'interval',
            'seconds': 120
        }, {
            'id': 'second',
            'func': 'app.zlty:secondRoutes',
            'trigger': 'interval',
            'seconds': 300
        }, {
            'id': 'third',
            'func': 'app.zlty:thirdRoutes',
            'trigger': 'interval',
            'seconds': 1860
        }
    ]
```

wsgi.py

```
from app import app, scheduler, zlty

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler.start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_autodoc import Autodoc
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_pushjack import FlaskAPNS
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
auto = Autodoc(app)
mail = Mail(app)
clientapns = FlaskAPNS()
clientapns.init_app(app)
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)

from app import zlty, models
```

Comment: You may want to describe the problem you're having with something more elaborate than "doesn't work".

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I am getting a similar issue, except with my program I am currently running just flask_apscheduler.  When I run it once it works, what I mean is that it will run the task and also create a test.db file and store the job.  However, when I run my app again I get the error `apscheduler.jobstores.base.ConflictingIdError: 'Job identifier (job1) conflicts with an existing job'`  My code is similar to the above, there are some slight changes, which I can show you if you need them.

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242710/flask-apscheduler-conflicting-job-error